# How to Plot the temperature and heat flux of the heat conduction problem

Tags: plotting, heat-equation

**This is a 1-D heat conduction problem for a circular rod with 5cm, T(x,0)=0, T(0,t)=100, T(infinite, t)=0.

I am trying to use the finite numerical method, how could I plot the temperature profile and heat flux at the wall x=0cm, and x=5cm?  **

```
λ = 0.0035
imax = 5;
lmax = 300;
For[i = 1, i < imax, i++, T[0, i] = 0]; 
For[l = 0, i < lmax + 1, l++, T[l, 0] = 100; T[l, imax] = 0]; 
For[l = 0, l < lmax, l++,
 For[i = 1, i < imax, i++,
  T[l + 1, i] = λ*(T[l, i + 1] - 2*T[l, i] + T[l, i - 1]) + 
    T[l, i]]]
a = Table[T[l, i], {l, 0, lmax}, {i, 0, imax}];
```

Comment: Consider replacing your `For[]` loops with `Do[]` loops at the very least.

Comment: i try to replace it later, but now i am focusing on how to plot the temperature and flux